# What is the akin to C/C++ INT_MAX macro in Java

Tags: java

Like C/C++ have the `INT_MAX` macro `(#include<limits.h>)` to set a variable to INFINITY. 
I was wondering if there is a similar function/macro in JAVA. I want to set an integer variable to INFINITY.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: INT_MAX != INFINITY...

Comment: INFINITY is a floating-point value.

Answer (score 3):

The `static` MAX_VALUE variable of the Integer class is what you want.

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

However, this isn't as useful in Java, since `int` values in Java are 32 bits no matter what.

Go to the following web page to learn more about the Integer class:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: Still very useful though, since it is easier and definitely much clearer to use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` than writing the constant.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't supports infinity in int type. The only way to represent an infinity number in Java is with the double type:

```
double infinity = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
```

Look at here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY

Comment: Infinity actually isn't an int in C either. That was an error in the question.